# How to convert a string array to its ASCII equivalent?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm a couple of weeks in too my GSCE Computer Science Coursework and lots of people have been stuck on how to convert a string array to its ASCII equivalent.

I am using this code:

```
c = input("Enter a character: ")
print ("The ASCII vlaue of '" +c+ "' is ",ord(c))
```

but it doesn't work for the an entire string.

So what I'm asking is how do you convert a string array to its equivalent ASCII code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a search would find you your answer, I strongly advice to do so first.

You would use something like this:

```
r = [ord(c) for c in s]
```

and you can (course)work from there

HTH,
Edwin.

Comment: I have tried your code and for some reason with the [ ] - it comes up with a syntax error - and with the ( ) it outputs  this: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x03C9F1C0>     and i can't see why it is printing this?

Comment: Turns out all i had to write was :     for i in string: print (ord(i))

Comment: You might want to flag my answer as "answer" then :-)